# Adding Targets to Bar Chats

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am looking at putting together a bar chart that would also include a "target" visual.

Example of what I am thinking:

[image]

I have managed to get the above bar chart going except for the red line and flag - which shows the difference to the current value to the target set. Obviously when this is met there would be a slight different visual - the flag turning green but first steps would be to get the flags in.

Has anyone ever done anything similar to this that they may be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I wonder if you could do something with one of the Gantt visualisations in the library?

Comment: Use a Bullet chart visual, it will have what your looking for. it will have colour boundaries, targets, i recommend the https://okviz.com/bullet-chart/ OKVIS, its in the custom visual store

Comment: @Jon thank you for that I will give it a go and see how I get on with it.

Comment: @JeffUK will make sure to check out your recommendation as well